# Component Scan with both including package and excluding a class is not working SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to scan a package com.training and want to exclude a specific class(SDIAuthorizerConfig.java) from scanning in componenet scan but it doesnt seems like working

```
package com.training.execution.tom.action;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;

import com.training.foundation.core.application.SDIServiceApplication;
import com.training.foundation.core.authorizer.config.SDIAuthorizerConfig;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.training",excludeFilters = @Filter(type= FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value=SDIAuthorizerConfig.class))
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class TOMActionServiceApplication extends SDIServiceApplication{
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(TOMActionServiceApplication.class, args);
        }

}
```

And getting this below error while starting the application in tomcat

```
Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'SDIAuthorizerFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authorizer'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'SDILDAPAuthorizer': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'populator'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SDIAuthorizerConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'sdi.ldap.url' in value "${sdi.ldap.url}"
```

the above property is being referenced inside SDIAuthorizerConfig class which I don't want my component scan to include so I have used the below but it still being scanned.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.training",excludeFilters = @Filter(type= FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value=SDIAuthorizerConfig.class))
```

Comment: Are you sure that the configuration isn't included somewhere else instead of only being component scanned?

Comment: @deinum yes it isn't included anywhere

Comment: Isn't it included in a library that automatically loads it, that is the kind of thing I'm hinting at or that it is part of some auto-configuration of a library you are using?